# how to replace all hyphenated words

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace all the hyphenated words in string with their separated versions. I am able to detect hyphenated words but I could not replace them with seperate versions. How can I do that?

This is the example and a sample code :

```
import re
text = "one-hundered-and-three- some text foo-bar some--text"
re.findall(r'\w+(?:-\w+)+',text)
# returns: ['one-hundered-and-three', 'foo-bar']
# I want to modify text as follows:
#  text_new = "one hundered and three- some text foo bar some--text"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `re.sub()` with a function for the `repl` argument:

```
In [12]: re.sub(r'\w+(?:-\w+)+', lambda match: match.group(0).replace('-', ' '), text)
Out[12]: 'one hundered and three- some text foo bar some--text'
```

I wrote it as a one-liner here, but I think it would be clearer if the lambda were moved out into a named function.

Answer (score 1):

`re.sub()` with positive lookahead and lookbehind:

```
import re

text = "one-hundered-and-three- some text foo-bar some--text"
print(re.sub(r'(?<=\w)-(?=\w)', ' ', text))

# one hundered and three- some text foo bar some--text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a really simple pattern:

```
\b-\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary.
- `-` Hyphen.
- `\b` Word boundary.

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/FQB3Ub/1).

---

Python demo:

```
import re

text = "one-hundered-and-three- some text foo-bar some--text"
print(re.sub(r'\b-\b', ' ', text))
```

Prints:

```
one hundered and three- some text foo bar some--text
```